# NSDictionary - Parsing item out of a return JSON service

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I'm trying to work with a web service that does some mad stuff. Part of the service is returning a value that looks like this screen shot.

[image: WebService Returned Data]
Below is my code just trying to loop through an NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *platesJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

 for(id key in platesJson) {
        id myvalue = [platesJson objectForKey:key];
        NSString *myValue = [[platesJson objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"value"];
    }
```

I have tried looping over the Dictionary of arrays and pulling out the information yet it seems to always return nil or crash entirely. Ironically the screen shot with the value of 0 is the error for this web service that I'm trying to put an if condition around.

I have also tried the following resulting it nil as well;

```
for (int i = 0; i< platesJson; i++)
    {
     NSString *myValue = [[platesJson objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"value"];
    }

if(myValue == 0){
//Alert the user no data found
}
else{
//Continue on....
}
```

I'm sure its something very simple just stuck to the best way to approach it with the correct syntax.

Comment: Please change NSString to NSArray or NSMutableArray and then try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *platesJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

 for(id key in platesJson) {
        id myvalue = [platesJson objectForKey:key];
        NSString *myValue = [platesJson objectForKey:key];
    }
```

I guess this will work,

`[platesJson objectForKey:key]`Will get value. If the value is a Dictionary,you need to loop in again. But in the image you post, it is just a simple Dictionary

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this way does work for the id/key. The issue I was having was that the key is dynamic (meaning the value can be 0,1,2,3 etc. But you are correct in stating that the code will work. I will need to rethink the logic however. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** sure the value at key is a `NSDictionary`, you obtain that that like this:

```
NSDictionary *myValue = JSON[ key ];
```

And you can get values from `myValue` as exactly same:

```
NSString *someString = myValue[ @"KLSL" ];
```

Note the first element in JSON is an NSArray or NSDictionary.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Jan, the value is dynamic so the KLSL portion of the code will always change. The web service that I am consuming does some weird stuff and I was trying to bend objective c. Clearly I need to rethink this. Thanks for the quick replay!